# Tweak Visio 2013 context menu

Tags: c#, visio, visio2013

Is it possible to disable some functions from the context menu in Visio 2013 for visio control?

I want to remove buttons for painting and changing shapes as I want to use only specific shapes in my visioControl.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for replace shape button. I can set [PageLockReplace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj228446.aspx) property of the `pageSheet` to `TRUE`:

```
visioControl1.Document.Pages[1].PageSheet.Cells["PageLockReplace"].FormulaU = "TRUE";
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was also looking to completely hide that floating control button panel on right-click on the shape and show my context menu